# Why we need <T> before void?

Tags: java, parameterized-types

I'm learning Java generics. I found the first <T> to be difficult to understand: if the method returns nothing, what does the <T> before void means?

```
public static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {                          
    for (T o : a) {
        c.add(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: It means "Give me an array of some unspecified type we'll call `T` and a collection of the same type."

Comment: It declares that for the code in this method, `T` can represent any type, instead of representing a specific type called `T`.

Comment: `<T>` and `void` don't conflict here, or mean anything to each other